# Supply Chain shortage drug Public Data Repository

Tags: online-resources, supply-chain, data

I don't know if I'm in the right place but I have a relevant problem. I need a dataset on drug supply shortages because I need it in my graduation thesis.
PS: I looked everywhere but couldn't find anything.
Please if you have any ideas where I can find some.

Answer (score 1):

Try plugging "drug shortage" and similar phrases into Google's [dataset search engine](https://datasetsearch.research.google.com/).